# Can't call _mm_dp_ps

Tags: c, linux, eclipse-cdt, sse, opensuse

I am trying to port some code that used to run on window to opensuse 12.1. But I am having problem with compiling a section of the code that use SSE instruction.

The opensuse is running on an intel Core i7 with these flags:
`fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ida arat dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid`.

Most of the SSE instruction are fine, but the compiler can't seem to know: `_mm_dp_ps`.
It is also complaining about `__builtin_ia32_pshufd` and `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32`.

Can anyone please help me? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you included the appropriate headers? Also, you may need to specify a compiler flag to enable SSE4 support.

Answer (score 1):

`_mm_dp_ps` and `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32` are both SSE4.1 - so you need:

```
#include <smmintrin.h> // SSE 4.1 intrinsics
```

and you also need to compile with:

```
$ gcc -msse4.1 ...
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for a quick reply. I do have both the include and the compile flags, but the compiler still unable to find it.

Comment: Are you getting any other warnings or errors prior to the errors for the intrinsics ? E.g. for missing #include files ?

Comment: There are warnings, but none that are in the function that calls these functions.

Comment: All of the warnings are about unused variables.

Comment: OK - well all I can suggest is to try compiling directly from the command line to see where the problem is coming from.